# Twitter Widget Timeline Code works everywhere except my network

Tags: wordpress, twitter

Thanks guys for any ideas you may have. I have DSL with Windstream and use their Sagemcom modem/router. I have embedded the stock twitter widget code into a wordpress site and even uploaded a simple html file with the embedded code and it doesn't render on my home network but the same laptop will render the timeline correctly outside my network. I tried other devices/pc's/macs on my home network and nothing will display the timeline. But take them off network and it works. I do have openDNS configured but as of right now it is set to 'Block nothing'. I've been through the router and adjusted settings with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Update - Not sure what changed but the timeline started working again today. I've been battling this for about a week and don't know which piece of the puzzle was having the problem. But as of right now it is fixed :)